# How does transmission rate scale with number of of lanes in MIPI CSI2?

Tags: csi

What I'm actually interested in is how non-MIPI data is converted to CSI2. Say I'm feeding a P-bit pixel to a CSI2 camera with *n* data lanes, how are the bits shared among the data lanes? If the pixel was serialized into a P-bit word, or if the pixel came in from a P-bit parallel bus (doesn't matter), does each lane simply take P/n of P bits and just transmit them (perhaps adding some overhead)? If that is the case then data rate *C* is *scaled down* proportionally to *C/n*.

I tried looking it up on the MIPI Alliance website itself but I couldn't find anything solid in their PHY overviews. Also I'm not sure if I'm asking about  confidential IP here.